# return value of a method(java)

Tags: java, variables, methods, return, return-value

My question is about the return value of methods. In **method1**, which returns the value of 1, when I call it in **method2**, it does not ask me to put its value in a variable. Why is this so? Should not the value that a method returns Saves inside a variable? Now that **method1** returns the value of 1, this 1 is not stored in a variable either. Now that this is not a statement in **method2**.

```
public int method1(){
    return 1;
}

public  void method2(){
    method1();//Shouldn't it be like int value=method1();?
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`method1` is a function, `method2` is a method.
Functions can return values. Values can be assigned to the variables for storage and future use. But function calculation and value assignment are different operations and are not necessarily glued together. There will be no compilation error in your case, but the value returned from `get()` will be lost.

Comment: They are both methods.

Comment: @NomadMaker, agreed, I meant 'method' as in 'returns void'

Comment: But method1() is also a method.

Answer (score 0):

The `return type` defines and constrains the data type of the value returned from a `method`.

```
public int method1(){
    return 1;
}
```

Here, `1` is not stored like we do store value in variable. Then how it works?
`"`Java Virtual Machine (`JVM`) is a program or software which takes Java `bytecode` (`.class` files) and converts the `bytecode` (line by line) into machine understandable code.`"`

Whenever you use, `System.out.println(1);` it works in the same way. The class get converted into bytecode then converted to machine language.

```
public  void method2(){
    get();
}
```

This `method2()` also works the same way but has `get()` `nested` method. Remember that `method2()` doesn't have any `return type` and the value from `get()` method is lost.

Answer (score 0):

"Putting in" a value is simply assigning something to a variable. Compilers do not ask you to store variables. Every function has an allocated memory to store its return value. After the function finishes, it stores the value you return in that allocated place. Then its job is done. It is up to you what to do with it.